# Can I somehow read the iOS device logs before the phone is unlocked

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, boot

After a hard reset (holding power+home) I would like to be able to see the iOS System logs after the phone boots. Using Xcode I can open the "Devices" tool, but unless I unlock the phone I cannot attach to the device to see the logs.

Is there a way to see the iPhone device logs while the phone is booting? Either in real-time or as a log file that I can examine afterwards.

I have also tried using the "View device logs" button in the Devices Tool, but all that I can see in there are crash logs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible, there are few options out there, one of my favorites is idevicesyslog, do the following:

- Install brew on your mac:

  http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/
- Using brew, install libimobiledevice

  `brew install libimobiledevice`
- Once done, connect idevice to mac and type in terminal

  `idevicesyslog`

**Note**: if there is more than 1 device connected to the mac, you will need to specify the device udid you wish to work with. In order to get the device udid, run the following command:

```
idevice_id -l
```

Then run idevicesyslog, but this time specify the udid:

```
idevicesyslog -u <device udid>
```

Comment: Thanks, the libimobiledevice tool is really great, I love being able to pipe the log through grep to find what I'm looking for, but it suffers from the same problem as the xcode device log in that it will not let me see the logs unless I have unlocked the phone with the passcode. I'm starting to think that this is a security issue, the phone needs to be unlocked at least once after reboot if you want to connect to it. In that case; I guess that the answer to my question is no.